# How to deal with a feeding Support as AD Carry?

Tags: league-of-legends

Yesterday i played some normals and ended up as Ashe with a Nidalee support. Opponents were Alistar and Jayce which should have made an easy lane. Sadly Nidalee decided to be extremely aggressive - against my request at the start of the game - which got her killed twice before 5 minutes and several times afterwards.

From there on the opponents were easily able to bully me out of CS and Exp and eventually towerdive me for the kill.

Is there any way to deal with a situation where the opposing carry is 2-3 kills ahead in the very early game that is more effective than begging the jungler for ganks and hugging the tower while accepting to fall behind in CS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Rule #1: Stay alive**

If your support keeps feeding, you unfortunately can't do much about that. Of couse you can try to protect him and/or follow his engages, but if this would just end in you dieing too it would be the worst thing to do.

**Rule #2: Don't overestimate yourself**

You by yourself alone can't do much without a support. It already requires a lot of skill to sustain and keep on with CS on a 1vs2 Botlane. And if the opposing champions are even ahead of you, because they killed your support a couple of times it's even harder. Don't try to make things up in some heroic action, you will just die and give them even more advantage.

**Rule #3: Stay calm and CS**

As long as you don't get ganks you have to play passively. Just try to keep up at least a bit with the CS without getting yourself killed. In doubt just tower hug and take the last hits you can get there - even if you fall behind with CS then. In doubt ask the jungler if you can take Golems or Wolves (depending on your side of the map).

**Rule #4: Ask for ganks**

If the jungler doesn't come by himself ask for ganks. There is nothing wrong with that - if he's at least a half decent jungler he won't let you beg for them. Also your situation gives you one advantage -> most likely your lane will be pushed constantly, which means your jungler should have an easy time ganking. If your enemies are too strong you maybe even want to ask your AP Carry to help you release some pressure on your lane too.

**Rule #5: Don't give up**

Even if your team doesn't manage to gank your lane propery - don't give up. Maybe the other lanes are doing fine and will carry the game. But if you give up, your team lost it's support **and** it's AD Carry which will seal the defeat for your team.

Comment: You might also want to consider rushing a Wriggles instead of an infinity in this situation as well.